# fastest way to print an image on MacOSX

Tags: macos, printing

I need to print TIF images from a Java application. I implemented it by starting "lp" with the image file as an argument. This needs about 38 seconds on my Mac until the printer starts printing (the same time if I start a terminal and just enter "lp image.tif"). But when I double click the image and it is shown in the "Preview" application of the Mac, I can print it from this application and it needs 8 seconds (tested both multiple times to avoid any printer or printing system sleep mode). How can I print an image from my Java application (or terminal session) with the same speed? And I need the same for RTF documents, needs 34 seconds for a simple document.

Comment: I am not sure if you are worried about the delay in the pages coming out, or how long your Java (or Terminal) is held up. If it is just the latter, you can background the "lp" command and carry on what you were doing like this "lp file.tif &".

Comment: Thanks, but I want the pages come out faster. The "lp" command already returns immediately.

Comment: Not sure how desperate you are but you could try using Applescript to open Preview and print for you... http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=37474

Comment: Is it possible that Preview is maybe printing faster because it is only "previewing" and maybe not printing at full resolution? How big are the files? And how fast is the connection to your printer - FireWire/USB 2/wifi? What happens if you slightly down-res the files before printing?

Comment: I think using Applescript and Preview would be annoying for the user.

Comment: The printer is connected with wifi and the TIF file with which I tested it is 350 kB. But looks like it is a problem of the "lp" system. I just tried this:
echo "hello" > test.txt; 
lp test.txt
And it needs 35 seconds, too, measuring from hitting the enter key for the command until the printer starts printing (it "dings" some time before, like if some big document was uploaded). The same file printing from "TextEdit" needs 5 seconds, no "ding".
So I guess I have to feed the native Apple printer somehow. Is there an easy way from the command line, or do I need some custom Carbon program for it?

Comment: I have been reading around on the Web, and some folks report that printing is remarkably faster if you turn off the firewall in "System Preferences->Security and Privacy". Obviously not a long-term solution, but maybe worth a try temporarily.

Comment: I tested it and turning off the firewall doesn't make a difference. Would be surprising anyway, because I can print fast from the Apple programs, and they have to use the wifi connected printer as well, just printing with "lp" from the Terminal (or my Java program) is slow.